# Nginx rewrite rules

Tags: nginx, rewrite

good day,
anyone can help me convert this .htaccess to nginx ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^data/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ index.php?dir=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^data/file/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ file.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

i've tried to convert with : http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

and the result :

```
location /data { 
rewrite ^/data/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ /index.php?dir=$1 break;
rewrite ^/data/file/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ /file.php?id=$1 break; 
}
```

but i still get not found on the converted rewrite rules.
thanks before for your help .
fyi i use Master Auto Index script

Comment: Perhaps you need `last` instead of `break`. I'm wondering about why there are 2 captures but only the first is used though (already so in the apache version).

Comment: i've tried that before and no luck ...